# Validate iPhone application in in XCode 3.2.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have built my application using "Build and Archive" and the version shows up in XCode Organizer. However; when I click the application and then "Validate Application..." nothing happens. When I check the console, the following entry is logged every time i click "Validate Application..."

Has anyone succeeded with this or experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate Application only works if you have a product on iTunes Connect that is in a 'waiting for binary upload' state. If you already have this in place (it should prompt you to select the application when you choose to validate) then I'm not sure - I know I lost a day to iTunes Connect last week where it wasn't processing things correctly (I assume they were doing some back-end maintenance or something) so it might just be a case of the tried and tested xCoder's 'Clean all Targets, Clean, rebuild' :(

Comment: Correct. You would think Apple at least gave an error message stating this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom -- nothing happened when clicking Validate Application -- after reinstalling my OS due to an unrelated problem. Apparently some components of Xcode are stored in the system folder, so I had to reinstall Xcode before I could validate and submit my app.